# Cancelling the partial of a coordinate, $\partial q$, with the element of a coordinate, $dq$ in Physics

Tags: mathematics, integration

I've seen in many books, things like this ( I will be simple ):

$$\int \frac{\partial f}{\partial q} dq=\int df$$

where $f$ is a function of $q$ and other coordinates.

I just axiomatically assumed that this operation was physically right, without questioning it. But I did know that it was mathematically wrong.

So, why we can do this? Is this some kind of approximation?

Comment: That's just the chain rule + integration by substitution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about physics.

Comment: Could you explain me better this chain rule + integration?

Comment: if $f=f(q,p)$, then $df =\partial f /\partial q dq + \partial f /\partial p dp$ in general. So this notation is sort of incorrect, but what is meant usually is that you perform integration with the other variable held constant.

Comment: I think this question is important - it is important for "doing" Physics. If we don't know why is correct to do what I showed above, then we are "doing" Physics wrongly. Doing things by memorizing, or just because it seems correct, isn't healthful. In my case (and I believe that I'm not the only one) I've been doing this operation for too many years without questioning it. It could be simple to understand, or I could be dumb, but I believe that this question will help more people, and for sure, it is important for Physics students. I can't see another server where I should do this question.

Comment: It's a pure math question. There's no "physical approximation" or somesuch involved, it is one of the basic properties of integration. If the question is why this works for a partial $\partial$ instead of the full derivative $\mathrm{d}$, then the answer is either what @DepeHb said or that someone used the wrong notation. Still, nothing about that is about physics, it's a general property of integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we have a function $f$ that is a function of several variables $p$, $q$, $r$, etc then we can write a [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) of $f$ as:

$$ df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial p} \text{d}p + \frac{\partial f}{\partial q} \text{d}q + \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \text{d}r + \, ... $$

If we're holding all the variables constant except for $p$, so $\text{d}q = \text{d}r = 0$ then this simplifies to:

$$ df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial p} \text{d}p $$

which gives you the result you quote. As several of the comments have noted this is really a maths question, though it's the sort of thing we use a lot in physics, and you should check [the Wikipedia link on total derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) if you want to pursue this further.